# Sum of numbers, clearer version of JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help creating a function that:

-The total sum of all the numbers from all lunchtime that the user has entered so far is calculated and stored in the HTML page.
(lunch + breakfast + dinner etc.)

-Sum of all dishes from one lunchtime
(lunch + lunch + lunch etc.)

Any suggestions? Below is what I have so far (JS code works but looks terrible ...):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
        <a>Sum</a><br>
      <div>
          <a class="expenses_sum_s_kcal"></a>   kcal      <b></b>
          <a class="expenses_sum_s_fat"></a>    g(fat)    <b></b>
          <a class="expenses_sum_s_protein"></a>g(protein)<b></b>
          <a class="expenses_sum_s_carbs"></a>  g(carbs)  <b></b>
      </div>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li> Lunch </li>
          <ul>
            <li  class="expenses_s_kcal">    <b> 100 kcal </b></li>
            <li  class="expenses_s_fat">     <a> 10 g     </a></li>
            <li  class="expenses_s_protein"> <c> 10 g     </c></li>
            <li  class="expenses_s_carbs">   <d> 10 g     </d></li>
          </ul>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li> Lunch </li>
          <ul>
            <li  class="expenses_s_kcal">    <b> 200 kcal </b></li>
            <li  class="expenses_s_fat">     <a> 20 g     </a></li>
            <li  class="expenses_s_protein"> <c> 20 g     </c></li>
            <li  class="expenses_s_carbs">   <d> 20 g     </d></li>
          </ul>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li> Breakfast </li>
          <ul>
            <li  class="expenses_s_kcal">    <b> 300 kcal </b></li>
            <li  class="expenses_s_fat">     <a> 30 g     </a></li>
            <li  class="expenses_s_protein"> <c> 30 g     </c></li>
            <li  class="expenses_s_carbs">   <d> 30 g     </d></li>
          </ul>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
            var expenses = $('.expenses_s_kcal');
            var expenseTotal = $('.expenses_sum_s_kcal');
            expenseTotal.html('0');
            $.each(expenses, function (index, object) {
                var boldTag = $(object).find('b');
                if (boldTag && boldTag.length > 0 && $(boldTag[0]).html() != '') {
                    expenseTotal.html(parseInt(expenseTotal.html()) + parseInt($(boldTag[0]).html().replace(/,/g, '')));
                }
            })
        });

$(document).ready(function () {
            var expenses = $('.expenses_s_fat');
            var expenseTotal = $('.expenses_sum_s_fat');
            expenseTotal.html('0');
            $.each(expenses, function (index, object) {
                var boldTag = $(object).find('a');
                if (boldTag && boldTag.length > 0 && $(boldTag[0]).html() != '') {
                    expenseTotal.html(parseInt(expenseTotal.html()) + parseInt($(boldTag[0]).html().replace(/,/g, '')));
                }
            })
        });

$(document).ready(function () {
            var expenses = $('.expenses_s_protein');
            var expenseTotal = $('.expenses_sum_s_protein');
            expenseTotal.html('0');
            $.each(expenses, function (index, object) {
                var boldTag = $(object).find('c');
                if (boldTag && boldTag.length > 0 && $(boldTag[0]).html() != '') {
                    expenseTotal.html(parseInt(expenseTotal.html()) + parseInt($(boldTag[0]).html().replace(/,/g, '')));
                }
            })
        });


</script>
</body>
```

```
https://jsfiddle.net/amWilq/m734t5ko/13/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, you should fix your HTML markup - it's not valid. A `<ul>` cannot be a child of a `<ul>` - only list elements can be children of a `<ul>`.

Make an array of sums, initialized to 0. Iterate over each expense `<li>`, using the index of its location in its parent to figure out which sum index to add it to.

At the end, iterate over the sums again and assign the sum to the associated index in the total `<div>`. To make this easier. make `<span>`s inside the total div to indicate where the populated results should go.

```js
const targets = $('.target');
const sums = [...targets].map(_ => 0);
$('li li').each(function() {
  const i = $(this).index();
  sums[i] += Number(this.textContent.match(/\d+/)[0]);
});
sums.forEach((sum, i) => {
  targets[i].textContent = sum;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
        <a>Sum</a><br>
      <div>
          <a class="expenses_sum_s_kcal"></a><span class="target"></span> kcal      <b></b>
          <a class="expenses_sum_s_fat"></a><span class="target"></span>g(fat)    <b></b>
          <a class="expenses_sum_s_protein"></a><span class="target"></span>g(protein)<b></b>
          <a class="expenses_sum_s_carbs"></a><span class="target"></span>g(carbs)  <b></b>
      </div>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li> Lunch 
          <ul>
            <li  class="expenses_s_kcal">    <b> 100 kcal </b></li>
            <li  class="expenses_s_fat">     <a> 10 g     </a></li>
            <li  class="expenses_s_protein"> <c> 10 g     </c></li>
            <li  class="expenses_s_carbs">   <d> 10 g     </d></li>
          </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li> Lunch
          <ul>
            <li  class="expenses_s_kcal">    <b> 200 kcal </b></li>
            <li  class="expenses_s_fat">     <a> 20 g     </a></li>
            <li  class="expenses_s_protein"> <c> 20 g     </c></li>
            <li  class="expenses_s_carbs">   <d> 20 g     </d></li>
          </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li> Breakfast
          <ul>
            <li  class="expenses_s_kcal">    <b> 300 kcal </b></li>
            <li  class="expenses_s_fat">     <a> 30 g     </a></li>
            <li  class="expenses_s_protein"> <c> 30 g     </c></li>
            <li  class="expenses_s_carbs">   <d> 30 g     </d></li>
          </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```